# Android NDK OpenGL; a slight slowdown

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, unity-game-engine

I wrote a simple OGL ES 2.0 program running on my Tegra2-based Android 2.2 device. It simply renders a big quad on the screen with some diffuse and specular lighting (no normal mapping). Obviously, I was curious about the performance. I measure it by computing a sum of delta times for one second and then divide that sum by the total number of FPS counted. Here's the code:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;
lastTime = currentTime;

timeCounter += deltaTime;
FPS++;

if (timeCounter >= 1000)
{
    System.out.println(FPS + "    " + (float)timeCounter/(float)FPS);

    timeCounter = 0;
    FPS = 0;
}
```

After I run the program, the first 2-3 measurements (seconds) give me something around 31-33 FPS but after that time it drops to 28-29 for one measurement, and finally to 26 and stays at this number. What is interesting here is that 26 = 52/2 and no matter what I do I cannot make my program run faster than with 52 FPS, even with the simplest solid-colored fragment shaders. Moreover, changing the shader a little bit (by removing pow function from the specular compuations for instance) does not affect the performance - still 26 FPS. There has to be a more performance-heavy (or -lighter) change to see the FPS changed. So I am wondering if there is any synchronization I am falling into here? Anyone expierienced anything like that?

I also made a simple program in Unity 3D, which does exactly what my original program does. I even copied the GLSL fragment shader and adapted it a little bit to conform with Unity 3D instead of using preferred Cg/HLSL language. The timings from the program in Unity clearly show a stable FPS around 31-33, which is what I get in my program for the first 2-3 seconds. I know that Unity is a good piece of software, but I would expect my program to perform, under the same conditions, almost exactly the same :).

Comment: What about System.out.println itself?

Comment: Erm, is your eq. correct?  You're calculating milliseconds per frame. It's a minor thing but in your code if you get 26 frames in 1 second it's going to say "FPS 38.46".  If it's saying "FPS 26", you're idling at 38 frames per second (1/26)

Comment: @Kay: I thought about it but I don't think it's the problem here. As I said, if I change fragment shader to something simpler, FPS raises, up to 52. So the println isn't the culprit that could be stalling. Besides, it's called barely once per second and it's not even included in the actual timing.

Comment: @Jerdak: I'm not sure if I understand... I add 1 to FPS variable each frame. After 1000ms has passed I display this number and that will be the actual number of frames that were generated throughtout the last second.

Comment: @maxest jerdak is right regarding the 2nd part timeCounter/FPS. What about [Application.targetFrameRate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html)

Comment: @Kay: I still don't get what could be wrong. I sum delta times to some variable. After a certain amount of time (in this case after 1000ms) I simply take that time and divide by the total number of frames generated, what should give me the average frame time of all frames generated. Equally well I could change that 1000 to 2000, and get avg. time of frames generated throughout the last 2 seconds. The only thing could be inaccurate here is that I should not reset timeCounter to 0, but instead subtract 1000 from it.

Comment: Apart from all this, I use the same code for measuring time of my app and Unity's app and still the FPS number is smaller for my app, despite the fact that exactly the same shaders are used.

Comment: @Kay: what do you mena with Application.targetFrameRate? I don't see how it relates to the situation I'm having.

Comment: I think I get what you're talking about :). The code "(float)timeCounter/(float)FPS" is not intended to display the FPS or what I think FPS is. I simply output two numbers: FPS *and* the avg time of frame. The fact that I separated them with four spaces made you think that I display only one number, but these are actually two.

Comment: @maxest targetFramerate can limit the FPS on mobile devices. I don't know the situation on Android, but on iPhone it's a multiple of 30.

Comment: I know what targetFramerate does but I don't see what it has to do with my situation. I don't want to limit the framerate. I want to measure the framerate and understand why an app written from scratch performs worse than the same up running under Unity

Comment: Wow, slow day for me.  I'm voting to close my own post as I clearly missed that in your code.

Comment: So... can we go back to the actual subject? :)

I also tested one Adreno 220-based phone and timings there are almost exactly the same, my small native app being a little little bit faster (probably due to the fact that the Unity app also render text with FPS). So timings here are as to be expected.